# Creating .cpp, .c, .h. and .java file templates

Tags: c++, template

This code builds template .cpp, .c, .h and .java files based on a file name and #include, import lines provided at the command line. The file opens after creation.

I am looking for a review of this code and seeing if there is anything that can be more efficient.

```
/* .cpp Example:
*     template awesome.cpp iostream vector string
* Output:
*
*     #include <iostream>
*     #include <vector>
*     #include <string>
*
*     using namespace std;
*
*     int main(int argc, char * argv[])
*     {
*
*        return 0;
*     }
*
* .c Example:
*     template something.c stdio.h
* Output:
*
*     #include <stdio.h>
*
*     int main(int argc, char * argv[])
*     {
*
*        return 0;
*     }
*
*
* .h Example:
*     template awesome.h vector string
*
* Output:
*
*     #ifndef TEST_H
*     #def TEST_H
*
*
*     #include <iostream>
*     #include <string>
*
*
*     #endif // TEST_H
*
*
*
*
* .java Example:
*     template something.java util.* math.*
*
* Output:
*
*     import java.util.*;
*     import java.math.*;
*
*     public class something {
*
*        public static void main(String[] args) {
*
*
*
*
*        }
*     }
*
*********************************************************/

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

// helper functions
string getFileType(string & filename);
void addImportAndIncludeLines(vector<string> & linesOfFile,
                              string & fileType, char * dependency);
void buildFile(vector<string> & linesOfFile, string & fileType);
void buildCOrCPlusPlusFile(vector<string> & linesOfFile, string & fileType);
void buildHeaderFile(vector<string> & linesOfFile, string & filename);
void buildJavaFile(vector<string> & linesOfFile, string & filename);
void writeToFile(vector<string> & linesOfFile, string & filename) throw(string);
void addHeaderFileDeclaration(vector<string> & linesOfFile, string & filename);
void capitalizeHeaderFileName(string & filename);


/*********************************************************
* main - handles the command line arguments and builds
* the template file, then opens it.
*********************************************************/
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
   // declare variables
   string filename;
   string fileType;
   vector<string> linesOfFile;


   // make sure something was actually passed in
   // if not, show proper usage
   if (argc > 1)
   {
      filename = argv[1];
   }
   else
   {
      cout << "Usage: template <filename> (optional: <files> <to> <include>)\n";
      return 0;
   }

   // get the file extension
   fileType = getFileType(filename);

   if (strcmp(fileType.c_str(), "h") == 0)
      addHeaderFileDeclaration(linesOfFile, filename);

   // add any #include / import files that were entered
   // at the command line
   for (int i = 2; i < argc; i++)
      addImportAndIncludeLines(linesOfFile, fileType, argv[i]);

   // build the template file
   buildFile(linesOfFile, filename);

   // try to write the template to the provided file name
   // then open it to begin editing
   try
   {
      writeToFile(linesOfFile, filename);

      // command to open the file after creation
      string command = "open ";
      command += filename;

      // open the file
      system(command.c_str());

   }
   catch (string error)
   {
      cout << error << endl;
   }



   return 0;
}

/*********************************************************
* returns the file extension
*********************************************************/
string getFileType(string & filename)
{
   return filename.substr(filename.find('.') + 1);
}

/*********************************************************
* addHeaderFileDeclaration adds the #ifndef statement
* for the header file
*********************************************************/
void addHeaderFileDeclaration(vector<string> & linesOfFile, string & filename)
{
   string headerDeclaration = filename.substr(0, filename.find('.'));
   capitalizeHeaderFileName(headerDeclaration);
   string ifStatement = "#ifndef ";
   ifStatement += headerDeclaration;
   linesOfFile.push_back(ifStatement);
   string defStatement = "#def ";
   defStatement += headerDeclaration;
   linesOfFile.push_back(defStatement);
   linesOfFile.push_back("\n");

}

/*********************************************************
* capitalizeHeaderFileName capitilatizes the provided
* filename and adds '_H' to it for the #ifndef statement
*********************************************************/
void capitalizeHeaderFileName(string & filename)
{
   transform(filename.begin(), filename.end(),filename.begin(), ::toupper);
   filename += "_H";

}

/*********************************************************
* addImportAndIncludeLines adds the dependency properly
* formatted based on the file type:
* #include <dependency>;
* import java.dependency;
*********************************************************/
void addImportAndIncludeLines(vector<string> & linesOfFile, string & fileType, char * dependency)
{

   // decide whether to #include or import.java.. based on
   // file extension
    switch (fileType.at(fileType.size() - 1)) {
        case 'c':
        case 'h':
        case 'p':
        {
            string includeString = "#include <";
            includeString += dependency;
            includeString += ">";
            linesOfFile.push_back(includeString);
            break;
        }
        case 'a':
        {
            string importString = "import java.";
            importString += dependency;
            importString += ";";
            linesOfFile.push_back(importString);
            break;
        }

    }
}

/*********************************************************
* buildFile builds the correct file based on file type
*********************************************************/
void buildFile(vector<string> & linesOfFile, string & filename)
{

    // calls the proper template builder based on file extension
    string fileType = getFileType(filename);

    switch (fileType.at(fileType.size() - 1)) {
        case 'p':
        case 'c':
            buildCOrCPlusPlusFile(linesOfFile, fileType);
            break;
        case 'h':
            buildHeaderFile(linesOfFile, filename);
            break;
        case 'a':
            buildJavaFile(linesOfFile, filename);

    }
}


/*********************************************************
* buildCPlusPlusFile - builds the template .cpp file plus
* the #include lines added at the command line
*********************************************************/
void buildCOrCPlusPlusFile(vector<string> & linesOfFile, string & fileType)
{
    if (strcmp(fileType.c_str(), "cpp") == 0) {
        linesOfFile.push_back("\nusing namespace std;");
    }
    linesOfFile.push_back("\nint main(int argc, char * argv[])\n{\n");
    linesOfFile.push_back("\treturn 0;\n}");

}


/*********************************************************
* buildHeaderFile - builds the template .h file plus
* the #include lines added at the command line
*********************************************************/
void buildHeaderFile(vector<string> & linesOfFile, string & filename)
{
   string headerDeclaration = filename.substr(0, filename.find('.'));
   capitalizeHeaderFileName(headerDeclaration);
   linesOfFile.push_back("\n");
   string endIf = "#endif // ";
   endIf += headerDeclaration;
   linesOfFile.push_back(endIf);
}


/*********************************************************
* buildJavaFile - builds the template .java file plus
* the import lines added at the command line
*********************************************************/
void buildJavaFile(vector<string> & linesOfFile, string & filename)
{
   // adds the class name based on the file name
   string className = "\npublic class ";
   className += filename.substr(0, filename.find('.'));
   className += " {";
   linesOfFile.push_back(className);

   // ...a lot of \'s, sorry!
   linesOfFile.push_back("\n\tpublic static void main(String[] args) {\n\n\n\n\n\t}\n}");

}


/*********************************************************
* writeToFile writes the template to a file with the
* provided file name.
*********************************************************/
void writeToFile(vector<string> & linesOfFile, string & filename) throw(string)
{
   ofstream output;
   output.open(filename.c_str());

   // throws error if the file can't be opened to write
   if (!output.is_open())
   {
      string error = "Error opening file \'";
      error += filename;
      error += "\'";
      throw error;
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < linesOfFile.size(); i++)
      output << linesOfFile.at(i) << endl;

   output.close();
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

- Do not use `using namespace std;`, instead explicitly use `std::` where required. [[Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)]
- Consider not using prototypes (which requires you to maintain the same function header in two places) unless necessary. This means putting `main()` at the bottom of your code and functions that it uses above it.
- Comments such as `// declare variables` add little value.
- Reverse the sense of the `if (argc > 1)` test and check `if (argc < 2)`, since you're going to `return 0` in the error branch anyway. That way you can skip the `else` and put `filename = argv[1]` outside the `if` block.
- Use `fileType == "h"` instead of `strcmp`. In general, avoid use of the `str*` library functions when using `std::string`.
- Always always always put braces around blocks, even if the block is one statement. Otherwise, you'll get errors like Apple's `goto fail` bug.
- In `getFileType()`, what happens if there is no `.` in the filename?
- In `addHeaderFileDeclaration()`, also consider the possible missing `.`.
- If filename contains more than one `.`, then the include guard will have a syntax error (since `.` is not permitted).
- `#def` should be `#define`.
- You should decide whether `linesOfFile` contains lines with or without a newline. In some places you do `linesOfFile.push_back("\n")` which will add *two* blank lines (perhaps you meant to do `linesOfFile.push_back("")`?)
- `capitalizeHeaderFileName` modifies its parameter. It would be better to take a `const string &` parameter and modify a temporary value within the function, and return that.
- Anywhere you take a `string &` parameter and don't modify it within the function, you should use `const string &`. For example the `fileType` parameter of `addImportAndIncludeLines`.
- Switching on the last character of the filename works for your current set of files, but will fail as soon as you get a conflicting last character (eg. `.scala` files would confict with `.java`). Use the full file extension when you need to make a decision based on file type.
- Only allowing `import` from the `java.*` namespace seems like an unnecessary limitation.
- In `buildFile()`, you are missing a `break;` in the `case 'a'`. It's true that it's not required there, but it's a bug just waiting to happen.
- In `buildHeaderFile`, you are computing the name of the include guard again, when you already did the same logic in `addHeaderFileDeclaration`. Consider unifying this somehow so you only have to compute it once.
- Do not `throw` a `string`! Use a proper exception class if you decide to use exceptions.
- Use an iterator to write out the lines of the file in `writeToFile`. In fact, you could use `std::copy()` and avoid the loop entirely.
- Consider using the `ofstream` constructor that takes a file name, instead of using a separate call to `open`.
- Don't use `filename.c_str()` because `ofstream` has an overload that takes a `string`.
- The `ofstream` destructor will automatically close the output file so you don't have to explicitly call `output.close()`.

Comment: *Don't use `filename.c_str()` because `ofstream` has an overload that takes a `string`.* - that's only available in C++11, which the OP may not be using (though it's still good to mention that point).

Comment: He tagged C++, not old-C++.

Comment: @DeadMG C++ 3.x is far from old, in fact probably the vast majority of C++ projects out there still use it. Now if he were using 1.x that'd be old.

Comment: `using namespace std;` is absolutely fine in the actual implementation, you just shouldn't use it in headers.

Comment: Same with prototypes, both help readability immensely. using std because it gets rid of unnecessary verbosity, and prototypes because the source code matches the application flow better. Prototypes also help understanding the source code quickly without going through the actual implementation.

Answer (score 10):

I would add:

- do not open the `ofstream` in `writeToFile`. Have `writeToFile` take an `std::ostream&` parameter instead of the file path. You can then try to open the file early (and fail fast if case be), instead of processing everything and finally failing because you can't create the file.
- the `fileType` parameter in `buildCOrCPlusPlusFile` is a gratuitous change with regards to the `filename` parameter taken by other `buildXXXFile` functions. Pass `filename`to uniformize signatures and deduce the `fileType` from within the function.
- use polymorphism instead of two identical switches in `addImportAndIncludeLines` and `buildFile`. (By the way, the implementation of `buildFile` is clearly calling for virtual dispatch) It means you can declare an interface and implement one class per file type.

This would lead to:

```
struct GeneratedFile {
    virtual void buildFile(vector<string> & linesOfFile, string & filename) = 0;

    virtual void addImportAndIncludeLines(vector<string> & linesOfFile, char * dependency) = 0;
};

struct JavaFile : GeneratedFile {
   /* Implement specific versions of virtual functions */
};

struct COrCPlusPlusFile : GeneratedFile {
   /* Implement specific versions of virtual functions */
};

struct HeaderFile : GeneratedFile {
   /* Implement specific versions of virtual functions */
};
```

With this, all you need to do is determine the `fileType` only once in your program, (instead of twice) and select the appropriate derived class once and for all, letting it take care of the specificities all by itself all the way to the end of the program.

Comment: Well formed answer.  these are the kinds of answers we are looking for on CodeReview!

Answer (score 9):

[The other answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/54341/2493) covered almost all things, but it is lacking some things :

- missing `#include <cstring>`, since you are using c string functions (for example `strcmp`), but since you shouldn't use them, feel free to ignore this point
- always catch exceptions by const reference. That is, change the catch clause to `catch (const string & error)`.
- in `addImportAndIncludeLines` and `buildFile` functions you are missing the default case, where you should throw an error if other options are not possible
- in `writeToFile`, consider enabling `ofstream`'s exceptions, instead of throwing `string`. That way, you do not need to check whether writing failed (which is also missing).

With last point, the function `writeToFile` looks like :

```
void writeToFile(vector<string> & linesOfFile, string & filename) throw(string)
{
   ofstream output;
   output.exceptions( std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit )
   output.open(filename.c_str());

   for (int i = 0; i < linesOfFile.size(); i++)
      output << linesOfFile.at(i) << endl;

   output.close();
}
```

but you need to catch `std::exception`.